# How to enable sitetositeprovenance reporting for custom processor in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a custom processor and enabled reporting task for capturing events
 But custom processor's events are not captured in SiteToSiteProvenance reporting task.

AFAIK all processors are not supported by SiteToSiteProvenance So where can I get the list of processors which does not support SiteToSiteProvenance reporting?

Can I enable it for all processors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask` should collect and transmit all provenance events on the system. There are a few properties you can configure on the RT to control what is sent:

- *Event Type* - allows for filtering what event types are collected using a comma-separated list
- *Component Type* - allows for filtering what component events are collected using a regular expression
- *Component ID* - allows for filtering which component events are collected using a comma-separated list of UUIDs

If all of these are set to empty (or a value you feel should include your custom processor), I would suggest following these further steps for diagnosing the issue:

1. Ensure you can see the provenance events locally using the provenance viewer. If you are using a custom processor and it extends `AbstractProcessor`, provenance event generation is provided for you at the framework level. If however, you do not extend that class or you need to capture `SEND` or `RECEIVE` events, which the framework cannot automatically detect, you have to manually record those events using code like below.
2. If you can see the provenance events locally, ensure the settings on the `SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask` aren't set to exclude them (either the settings mentioned above or the *Start Position* setting as well).

Code for manually recording provenance event inside `#onTrigger()`:

```
// Records a MODIFY_CONTENT event (given a stopWatch that was initialized before the work was performed)
session.getProvenanceReporter().modifyContent(flowFile, stopWatch.getElapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Hopefully this information helps.

Comment: I would also add that not all processors produce provenance events. If the processor doesn't modify the content or attributes and just routes the flow file to a relationship, typically there wouldn't be a provenance event for this. The framework takes care of most events, and processor code typically only has to care about SEND and RECEIVE events since the framework can't tell when a processor interacts with an external system.

Comment: Start Position is "End of Stream" and Component Type to exclude is "Connection" and remaining are empty and Custom processor is extending AbstractProcessor

Comment: Try setting _Start Position_ to "Beginning of Stream" and see if it sends any additional events. Did you verify that you can see the expected provenance events locally using the provenance viewer?